# How to join two nested subarrays (inside multidimensional array) elements in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In a big array of arrays, I need to join every two arrays, 
If I have the following array

```
array = [["string1","string2"],["string3","string4"],["string5","string6"],["string7","string8"]...........]
```

I need the following output as result

```
#  [["string1","string2", "string3","string4"],["string5","string6","string7","string8"]...........]
```

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".
Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `each_slice`

```
 p array.each_slice(2).map {|v| v.flatten}
```

Comment: Good one! ...or `{ |a,b| a+b }`.

Comment: Damn, that's really clean. Nice job

Comment: ``array.each_slice(2).map {|v| v.reduce(:+)}``

Comment: Working Great, thanks Rajagopalan